# Java | Prevent any special characters EXCEPT underscores

Tags: java, regex, string

As the title suggests, I want to check and prevent any special characters in a string. However, in doing so I prevent the underscore (which is fine to keep). Is there any way to allow underscores still?

**This is how I handle the check:**

```
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9&]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                Matcher m = pattern.matcher(String.join("", args));
                if (m.find()) {
                //Code
                }
```

Comment: Can't you just add `_` after `&`? Tested and works on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: You seem to be allowing & as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex expression is currently allowing any characters, digits and ampersands (&). Just add an underscore to the negated set:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^_a-zA-Z0-9&]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: What is the point of making this CASE_INSENSITIVE (which is expensive)? Seems the pattern already covers all uppercase and lowercase letters.

Comment: This is true; I was just making minimum modification to the given example. The `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` is redundant.